# AlchemyAPI call to ingest news by URL

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I use the AlchemyData News API to search for news articles by category to receive sentiment and company information.

Is there a way to instead of searching for an article, to feed an Article URL or headline to the service to have the article ingested to get sentiment and company info?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [AlchemyLanguage API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/alchemylanguage), specifically the [entity extraction feature](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/alchemylanguage/entity-extraction), to get this type of information about a specific article or body of text.

For example, you can issue